# Improve Site Top menu on Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I need to improve my site menu on mobile . It is working fine on pc . But for mobile users it requires improvements. site http://www.shadievent.com/

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. see how to ask a question on SO > http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . improve in what way ? what is your desired result ? what do you want to achieve? what have you tried ? where is your code ? do not link to external sites. this is NOT a code making site

Comment: on mobile my site top menu not looking great  please send me code for top menu on mobile . you can check code through inspect elements

Comment: well sorry. here on SO we don't do that. check free-lancing sites. here we are doing voluntary work , all we request is a bit of cooperation and involvement from the one that asks the question. good luck with your problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you may give other font color or may use other color for background of menu

Comment: Do you want to improve your menu?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in the web design you have up now, you can add a background color to your nav#nav-mobile or the ul inherently inside of it. I would also use toggling expandable divs on the mobile nav items that have children and avoid drop-downs on hover... since you can't really hover using a mobile device. Hope this helps. Good luck.